# Security policy PDF error in Imagick in Laravel app hosted on Azure

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service, imagick

Below is the Imagick code reading a PDF file.

```
    $img = new Imagick();
    $img->setResolution(300,300);
    $img->readImage($pdffile);
```

Below error appears in the log->

```
production.ERROR: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408 {"userI
d":1,"exception":"[object] (ImagickException(code: 499): attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAutho
rized/408 at /home/site/wwwroot/app/Http/Controllers/Sample.php:2812)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/site/wwwroot/app/Http/Controllers/Sample.php(2812): Imagick->readimage('/tmp/phpPPIrAu')
```

I added policy code in `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` but no effect.

Comment: What is the new policy for PDF? Show your change.

Comment: File is here->

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fRU9zQ-nc7ydHZI04u7DKv2uRoskz2lZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As you already raised a question in Q&A and as you got the response over there grab the information from there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491453/security-policy-pdf-error-in-imagick-in-laravel-ap.html